# Install libbluetooth-dev on Mac

Tags: macos, bluetooth, wiiuse

I've been looking forward to using the wiiuse library on my Mac.
When trying to install the library, when compiling with make I was told this :

```
>make wiiuse                          
gcc -Wall -pipe -fPIC -funroll-loops -O2 -I. -c classic.c -o release-x86_64-apple-darwin15.4.0/classic.o
In file included from classic.c:43:
./wiiuse_internal.h:49:11: fatal error: 'bluetooth/bluetooth.h' file not found
        #include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
                 ^
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [release-x86_64-apple-darwin15.4.0/classic.o] Error 1
make: *** [wiiuse] Error 2
```

My friend on Ubuntu solved it with sudo apt-get install libbluetooth-dev but I can't find anything on Mac.
If you have any idea about how to install wiiuse or libbluetooth-dev on mac, thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2):

I've just been looking for the same thing, came across this site saying it's not available on OSX, not sure how official it is though: http://rosindex.github.io/d/libbluetooth-dev/